# get value of a variable “outside” of a callback in android

Tags: android, interface, callback

There is a String `message` as a parameter in an interface method:

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String globalStringResult = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);

        getMediaInfo();
        Log.d("Result: ", globalStringResult); // Here result is Null

    }//TODO OnCreate End


    private void getMediaInfo() {
        FFmpeg.getInstance(this).execute(new String[]{"-version"}, 
                new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                globalStringResult  = message;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Here is this problem that I've faced many times but always ran from it. Now I want to deal with it if you help me.

I am executing `getMediaInfo()` method inside onCreate. When I log the result **inside onCreate after `getMediaInfo()` execution** , the result would be **null**. But if I run it inside an onClick button or something I get my desired result.

Is there any way that I could return callback message anywhere that I want?

Comment: Without seeing your onCreate it's hard to tell but my guess is that you are trying to use the variable before the Async call is returning it.  If you have code that depends on this variable you can move it into it's own method and call it from the onSuccess method.

Comment: It works from a Button because, `ClickListener` is an interface which has an inbuilt callback.

Comment: declare your variable outside of onCreate(); something like private String globalStringResult; as a global variable and do not set value yet.

Comment: @BakonJarser I've edited my question, my main goal is about using it outside

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your function getMediaInfo is asynchronous which means it could take some time before the onSuccess block is called and your value is set. Instead of relying on a variable I would suggest to use a callback function. That way your message will be passed to the callback function and you could use it anywhere.

```
public interface MyCallback{
    void success(String message);
}
```

Then you would need to modify your function as follows. Then where ever the callback is implemented you will receive the message and you can act on the value.

```
public void getMediaInfo(MyCallback callback){
 FFmpeg.getInstance(this).execute(cmdArray, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String message) {
        callback.success(message);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not familiar with FFmpeg, however, I would agree with your assumption that the `execute()` method is asynchronous. But, in this example I fail to see the added value in adding an interface callback to the callback method `onSuccess()`.

Comment: You are right about method being `asynchronous` but this will release me from old callback and tie me to a new one with the same situation

Comment: The point i was trying to make is that if you are dealing with async code you will need to stay async.

Answer (score 0):

If your further actions depend on the value set in onSuccess callback then simply call a function from this callback method. You need to provide more info on what exactly you are trying to do with this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous calls can be tricky but you have to wait until it is finished before the variable is available.  This means calling any methods that rely on the variable in the callback of the async call.  There's really no way around it.  You may want to make two version of the call; one for onCreate and one when you need to call it from other places.

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

private String globalStringResult = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);

    getMediaInfoOnCreate();
    // move any code below this line into the new method


}//TODO OnCreate End


private void getMediaInfo() {
    FFmpeg.getInstance(this).execute(new String[]{"-version"}, 
            new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String message) {
            globalStringResult  = message;
            codeThatNeedsToBeRunDuringOnCreateButAfterSettingGlobalStringResult();
        }
    });
}

    private void getMediaInfoOnCreate() {
    FFmpeg.getInstance(this).execute(new String[]{"-version"}, 
            new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String message) {
            globalStringResult  = message;
        }
    });
}

private void codeThatNeedsToBeRunDuringOnCreateButAfterSettingGlobalStringResult() {
    // put your moved code from onCreate here
    Log.d("Result: ", globalStringResult); // Here correct result will be logged
}

}
```